# How to use the railroad?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have a railroad running through my city area, and I've connected a few roads to it but that's about all I've done.

I don't see a train station or other builds to create that will take advantage of the rail road.

How do I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upgrade your city hall and get the department of transportation module added on to it. When this happens you will be able to build the train components needed to connect to it.

You can find the train components under the Transport menu (Looks like a bus) and then under the Trains section. If you hover over the items there it will show you the requirement in order to purchase that item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh thanks. I didn't know the city hall upgrades added new items to the menus. Is this true for the other upgraded, like education?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Yes it is. I added the Utilities first and received access to things like a recycling plant and better water systems and such. They all give you access to something.. I think Finance allows you to tax residential, commercial and industrial income separate from each other and the like.